# how do i convert Smali files to readable classes

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, apktool

so i have used apktool to convert an .apk file basically reverse re-engeneering but the classes have come in smali files which is hard to interprate.how do i convert the files to readable code

i have tried opening the code with different editors but still I  cant understand the code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) to reverse APKs and read classes' code in java.

Also you can use [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) to convert dex files to jar then use java decompilers to convert .class to .java, but i suggest you use jadx because it has a graphical user interface with a lot of tools to simplify reverse engineering.

Comment: Note that decompiler s like dex2jar and Jadx can fail to decompile certain methods and even more problematic the decompiler code can be wrong. That is something you have to keep in mind when looking at the decompiler code. Sometime looking at the small code is the only way to check what a function is doing.

Comment: @Robert exactly, but sometimes i need to just have a quick look at the decompiled code to identify some valuable things so i work with jadx but when I need to know the accurate functionality of a piece of code i prefer to read the smali bytecodes.